# Compatibility issue with Java

Tags: java, linux, compatibility

I wrote a Java code and compiled it with jdk1.8.0_60. After the `.class` file is generated I ran it and it was working properly. For distribution purpose, I removed the jdk's path from PATH (environment variable) and gave the path of jre1.8.0_60 which is installed in a seperate directory. When I am trying to run the same compiled file, it is showing the following error.
Please help me solving this issue. If there is something else that is required, please let me know. Thanks!

[image: The issue being faced]

Comment: And why did you do that?

Comment: If you want your application to run with older versions than java 8, use the javac -target option.

Comment: Check `java -version`

Comment: @WeareBorg I want to create my own environment for running my application. So I am planning to distribute the JRE package as well with the application so that even if the user doesn't have Java installed, the application would run. Please clear if I have any conceptual error regarding this.

Comment: @wero java version "1.4.2"  

gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

Comment: so you got the cause: Java 1.4 cannot run Java 8 compiled files. You need a Java 8 runtime (or compile with `-target` as suggested by Joop)

Comment: Well it looks like your JRE is version 1.4.2 and not 1.8.0. For your intentions, take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html, this allows to create native executable bundles, that include the JRE.

Comment: Not a good idea to deploy JRE directly within and that too the old one. You can give a online downloader link, this way the users will have the latest JRE. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: The correct way to be sure the user has the necessary version of Java is by deploying your application as a [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) application.  If there is a chance the user doesn't have any version of Java installed, use the [Deployment Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html) to provide the Web Start link on your page.

Comment: @JoopEggen, wero: thank you very much. That was really helpful and I also figured out how it is working.